# I have thousands of URLs including /?___store=3&___version=1659330000&__signature= What are these URLS?

Tags: store-view

When I crawl the site, I have thousands of URLs showing up with URLs such as this:
?___store=3&___version=(number similar to this 1659330000)&__signature=, and it ends with a timestamp. What are these URLs? Why is this happening? And how do I stop them from forming so they don't take over my crawl budget?

No other URLs contain store=1 or store=2. I'm also noticing that a lot of them have a 301 status code, are non-indexable, and are redirected.